# Vue3 - print function result into p vs print function to css section inside html tag

Tags: vue.js

let's say I have a very simple setup using `data()` and a function written in the `methods` part. With the function I'm returning a random number between 1 and 3, while the data contains an list of blog elements.

When displaying the result from randomNumber directly on the page using `<p>{{randomNumber()}}</p>` the value (1-3) get's printed. In my case I'm printing all posts from blogs using `v-for` on the parent div.

When however, trying to alter a css class with said number the number does not get printed. For this particular test I have made `.g1`, `.g2` and `.g3` with different style attributes. When inspecting the source code directly in the browser the `.blog-thumb` class has `g{{randomNumber()}}` as a second class.

i tried to call `randomNumber()` within the `blogs item` but I'm still unable to add the generated class to the css class section.

Thank you for your help or suggestions.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col" v-for="blog in blogs" :key="blog.id">

    <div class="blog-thumb g{{randomNumber()}}"> <!-- DOES NOT GET PRINTED -->

      {{randomNumber()}} <!-- GETS PRINTED -->

      <p class="date">{{ blog.date }}</p>
    </div>
    
    <h2>{{blog.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{blog.content}}</p>
</div>
```

**Vue:**

```
methods : {
  randomNumber : function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3+1);
  }
},

data() {
  return{
    blogs: [
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Amet consectetur adipisicing',
        date: 'March 3rd 2022',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum...'
      },
      {...}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fiddling with it for quite a while today I found this solution:

I changed the function to return a complete classname (in this case, g with a random number between 1 and 3)

```
randomNumber : function(){
    return 'g' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3+1);
}
```

in the html part I added the `v-bind` to the class and passed the function (`v-bind:class="randomNumber()"`)

```
<div class="col" v-for="blog in blogs" :key="blog.id">

    <div class="blog-thumb" v-bind:class="randomNumber()">
      <p class="date">{{ blog.date }}</p>
    </div>
    
    <h2>{{blog.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{blog.content}}</p>
</div>
```

with this, now every col blog-thumb class got another generated class added to it.